# Register a plugin in CRM

Tags: c#, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have read the following documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309580(v=crm.7).aspx) about how to register plugins.

I don't understand the the **bolded** **part**, perhaps someone can explain what it means:

> If so, you must enable custom code on the server and try again. For
>   more information see
>   **c3ee3447-ec0d-494e-8b35-4ec58ce93eea#bkmk_enablecode.**

For more information see Guid- hash tag- bkmk_enablecode, I mean, i have read a lot of technical threads, but this makes no sense to me !

What is this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for help using the content of another website.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a link to a KB article that went wrong. My guess is that they want you to go to [this location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328153.aspx#enable_disable).

For the record, I've done mostly on-line stuff so on-prem is not my strongest suit. However, the guess above (please keep in mind it's a guess, although an educated one) should still be valid.